# Django admin почему после сохранения inline models не видны в родительской форме?

Tags: django, django-admin

По какой-то причине, после сохранения модели `Project` в django-admin дочерние элементы не отображаются в форме, хотя само сохранение происходит.

Пробовал упразднить и `get_fields` и `get_inline_instances`, но это ни к чему не привело. 
При этом, `Activity`, отображается, а остальные - нет.

```
    class InlineActivityAdmin(GenericStackedInline):
        model = Activity
        form = ActivityForm
        extra = 1

    class InlinePriceAdmin(CompactInline):
        model = Price
        extra = 1

    class InlineInvoiceAdmin(CompactInline):
        model = Invoice
        readonly_fields = ['state']

    @admin.register(Project)
    class ProjectAdmin(FSMTransitionMixin, BaseAdmin):

        inlines = [
            InlineActivityAdmin,
            InlineInvoiceAdmin,
            InlinePriceAdmin,
        ]
        list_display = ['pk', 'state','address', 'assignment_phone_number', 'assignment_client_name']
        list_filter = ('state', )
        readonly_fields = ('state', 'assignment_phone_number', 'assignment_client_name')


        def get_fields(self, request, obj):
            if obj:
                if not request.user.is_superuser:
                    if obj.state == 'complete_work':
                        return ['state', 'address', 'assignment_phone_number', 'assignment_client_name', 
                        'project_service', 'project_trouble']
                    elif obj.state == 'started_diagnostic':
                        return ['state', 'address', 'assignment_phone_number', 'assignment_client_name', 
                        'diagnostic_service', 'diagnostic_trouble']
                    else:
                        return ['state', 'address', 'assignment_phone_number', 'assignment_client_name']
            return super(ProjectAdmin, self).get_fields(request, obj)

        def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj):
            inlines = []
            if obj:
                if not request.user.is_superuser:
                    if obj.state == 'take_invoce':
                        for inline_class in self.inlines:
                            if inline_class is not InlineInvoiceAdmin:
                                inline = inline_class(self.model, self.admin_site)
                                inlines.append(inline)
                        return inlines

            return super(ProjectAdmin, self).get_inline_instances(request, obj)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в том, что в группе у юзера, под которым я работал, не было прав на `change` , но были права на `add`.